# Java .txt username and password not working

Tags: java, netbeans, passwords

I was just experimenting with java (NetBeans) and I though up a quick text based adventure game. I'm trying to get it to check for your username and password in two text files "users.txt" and "passwords.txt" and i was following a guide on *Cave of Programming*

Here are the imports

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

This is where the errors are,

```
        private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       String usernametxt = "users.txt";
       String passwordtxt = "passwords.txt";  
       String user = null;
       String pass = null;
       try {
       // file reader for username \\
           FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(usernametxt);
           // file reader for password \\
           FileReader fr = new FileReader(passwordtxt);
           // buffered reader for username \\
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
           // buffered reader for password \\
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                // check for if user doesn't equal null \\
           while((user = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
               // if username equals first line of username.txt \\
               if (username.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(user)){
                   // check for if pass doesn't equal null \\
                   while((pass = br.readLine()) != null){
                   // if password equals first line of passwords.txt \\
                   if (password.getPassword().equals(pass)){
                       // if password = pass than it will exit \\
                   System.exit(1);
                }
                   // else continue \\
                   else{
                       continue;
                   }

               }
           }
       }
       bufferedReader.close();
       br.close();
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
      System.out.println("Unable to open file ");
   }
   catch(IOException ex){
       System.out.println("Error reading file");
       }
    }
```

Here are the text files

```
users.txt
matthew

passwords.txt
matt
```

Full code available here
http://textuploader.com/57urs

Newest Code Here
http://textuploader.com/577qk

feel free to ask me questions here.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Newest Code

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
   String usernames = username.getText();
   String passwords = password.toString();
   boolean signedin = false;
   String usernametxt = "users.txt";
   String passwordtxt = "passwords.txt";  
   String user = null;
   String pass = null;

   try {
       FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(usernametxt);
       FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(passwordtxt);

       BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
       BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);

       System.out.println("Username: "+br1.readLine());
       System.out.println("Password: "+br2.readLine());
```

// While loops not running (not a if statement error \

```
       while ((user = br1.readLine()) != null){
           // checks if username is not equal to usernames.txt \\
           if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(usernames)){
               System.out.println("while loop running, username (right)");
               break;
               }
               else{
               System.out.println("while loop running, username (wrong)");
               }
           }
       br1.close();


           while ((pass = br2.readLine())!= null){
               if (pass.equalsIgnoreCase(passwords)){
                 signedin = true;
                 System.out.println("While loop running, password (right)");
                 break;
              }
              else{
                System.out.println("While loop running, password (wrong)
              }
       }
        br2.close();
```

// Commented out the if statements because i dont want to to close while testing \

```
       //    if (signedin){
           //        System.out.println("SIGNEDIN = TRUE");
          //        new error1().setVisible(true);
        //       this.dispose();
   //   }
    //   if (!signedin){
     //      System.out.println("SIGNEDIN = FALSE");
     //      System.exit(1);
      // }

   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
       System.out.println("Unable to open file ");
   }
   catch(IOException ex){
       System.out.println("Error reading file");
   }
}
```

New Problem

The while loops do not run, this is confirmed when it doesn't print "While loop running, User/Pass", This is not a if/then statement error as I have added the else statement to print if the username is right or wrong. Please help, Thanks Matthew.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: not a very good code implementation. You are using nested while loops. You could first retrieve all the usernames and passwords from both the files in seperate lists and then start doing the comparsions.

Comment: All right ill try that

Comment: How do i get the stack trace?, i do not know what that is

Comment: It seems as if the variable *username* is not declared. I bet when you run this program it says something like NullPointerExeption.

Comment: On the full code you will see that the variable "username" is a jtextfield

Comment: Current Code: http://textuploader.com/57ujg

Comment: When you have problem in your code, then you have to tell us, what the errors/exception are and where they occur. Also post the Stacktrace. And if you don't know where to get, then google for something like "[IDE name] stacktrace".

Comment: The only error is that it won't take the values from the jtextfield and the jpassword field. i put in "matthew" and "matt" as the username and password, respectively. And it will just do nothign when I press "Login". And I can not find the stack trace for netbeans 8.1

Comment: Check edited code for updated code

Comment: yay, more problems. This time even though `signedin = false;` it still opens what it's supposed to open if `signedin = true`.

Comment: Current Code http://textuploader.com/577qk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood it correctly:

Two files:

- **users.txt** holds the usernames.
- **passwords.txt** holds the passwords.

We want:

1. Keep reading the user file until the file ends or we've found our user.
2. Read the corresponding line on the password file and check if the password matches.

Checking the code,  `while((user = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)` does the first part nicely. We DO want to keep reading the entire file trying to find our user, right?

but the nested while seems a bit fishy. We only need to check a SINGLE password for a given user, right? RIGHT?

Digging a bit deeper into your code, we see:

```
if (password.getPassword().equals(pass)) {
    // if password = pass than it will exit
    System.exit(1);
} // plus Lots of code...
```

Hey! I don't think `System.exit` does what you're looking for!

`System.exit` will exit the program, going back to DOS or whatever the cool kids are using these days. The integer it returns is called an error code, and can be used to feed info back to the terminal/shell that started our program.

The keyword you're most likely looking for is **`break`**: that will exit a given loop pronto, no questions asked.

Let's do some break/continue mashups! Suppose we "Win at life" if the password is indeed correct:

```
boolean winAtLife = false;
while((user = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    String candidatePassword = br.readLine();
    if (candidatePassword == null) {
        // So the password file is shorter than the userfile? 
        // We probably want to log or alert the poor DevOp guys. 
        // throwing an exception seems like the right thing to do here!
        break;
    }

    if (!user.equalsIgnoreCase(username.getText())) {
        // These are not the droid we're looking for, Better luck next line!
        continue;

        // Also notice that, since we KNOW that user can't be null,
        // we're using the force to save ourselves from dreaded NullPointerExceptions!
    }

    if (!candidatePassword.equals(password.getPassword())) {
        // Hmmm, wrong password, I guess?
        // Not sure what do do next, but we DO NOT need to keep looping
        // since we've found our droid/user/whatever.
        // So let's break and save some EC2 Cycles.
        break; 
    }

    // If we ever reach here, we got ourselves a winner!
    pass = candidatePassword
    winAtLife = true;
}
```

EDIT: Ok... So I've heard that:

1. The cool kids use Scanner nowadays.
2. Auto-closing resources is good for our health.
3. Something about separation of concerns and mixing domain-code with the UI. In code samples. Whatever.

So here we go, take two, now as a method:

```
public boolean checkCredentials(String username, String password) throws IOException {
    // these two are begging to be constants or inlined. 
    final String usernametxt = "users.txt";
    final String passwordtxt = "passwords.txt";

    if (username == null || password == null) {
        // You probably don't want this in production code.
        // Exceptions are your best friends when something unexpected occurs.
        return false;
    }

    try (final Reader fileReader = new FileReader(usernametxt);
         final Reader passwordReader = new FileReader(passwordtxt)) {

        Scanner userScanner = new Scanner(fileReader);
        Scanner passwordScanner = new Scanner(passwordReader);

        while(userScanner.hasNext()) {
            final String user = userScanner.next();
            if (!passwordScanner.hasNext()) {
                // So the password file is shorter than the userfile?
                // We probably want to log or alert the poor DevOp guys.
                // throwing an exception seems like the right thing to do here!
                return false;
            }
            final String candidatePassword = passwordScanner.next();
            if (!user.equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                // This is not the droid we're looking for
                // Also notice that, since we KNOW that user can't be null,
                // we're using the force to save ourselves
                // from dreaded NullPointerExceptions!
                continue;
            }

            if (!candidatePassword.equals(password)) {
                // Hmmm, wrong password, I guess?
                // Not sure what do do next, but we DO NOT need to keep looping
                // So let's return early and save some EC2 Cycles.
                return false;
            }

            // If we ever reach here, we got ourselves a winner!
            return true;
        }
    } // yay for autocloseable
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ill try this right now, also have you seen the updated code?

Comment: Nope, was too busy doing star wars jokes. :)

Comment: 1. what does ``username.getText()`` looks like?
2. I'll assume both files exist and are readable, OK? :)

Since you're doing two distinct loops, it will match if the password is in the password file no matter in which like. is that what you want?

Comment: Both files exist, users.txt has one user "matthew" and passwords.txt has one password, "matt". and username is the jtextfield that you input text into. and now im just doing one loop. and right now im just experimenting with txt files.

Comment: I've edited the answer to improve some of the coolness factor. it's the 21th century and people at the office keep saying something about scanners and stuff.

anyway, good luck with your code :)

Comment: Thank you, ill also try this

Comment: This one is easy. Your problem lies within `if (signedin = true)`.

Don't ever use this construct in java. the proper way of testing what you want is `if (signedin)`.

`(signedin = true)` should be read as: 'assign true to the signedin variable. :)

Comment: When doing if clauses, NEVER mention the true and false literals. It's just too easy to miss the second equals sign, and your compiler won't help you finding that.

Comment: New Error, While statements never activate. Please help. Now i have no idea why they are not activating.